# Spreadsheet gear keeping the file open

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, spreadsheetgear

Does the Spreadsheat gear dll or asp.net 5 provide any capabilities to keep the file open and ready constantly ? I am currently getting my workbook the following way:

```
public WorkbookRepository(IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment)
{
   this.appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
   string path = this.GetWorkbook();
   workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(path);
}

public string GetWorkbook()
{
   return appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath + "\\App_Data\\Book1.xlsx";
}
```

There is a lot of time spent on opening the file to fetch the data and saving the data to the file, even though it's not very good I would like to keep the file open at all times, so there is as little time spent as possible ,I am quite new  to the Spreadsheetgear library and I am not quite sure that the lib has capabilities to keep the file open constantly , I read somewhere that when it is not reading/writing it closes the file. What should I do to achieve the result I want ?